# How to open new screen while choosing in navigation drawer activity in android

Tags: java, android

Im very new for android.. I created simple project, Im using Navigation drawer. If i choose anyone option from that navigation means its overwrite in Mainactivity Screen. Because i wrote everything in Mainactivity.java. I want If i choose anyone option means its shows in new screen if i click back shows previous screen.. How to do.. Please anyone help me!

Thanks for advance!

My code here:
MainActivity.java

```js
import android.app.Activity;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

    List<DrawerItem> dataList;
    EditText mEdit;

    private String[] states;
    private Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       /* setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout_address);*/

       /* String[] city= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.city);
        autoTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.city_autoCompleteTextView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,city);

        autoTextView.setThreshold(1);
        autoTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);*/

        // Initializing
        dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        // Add Drawer Item to dataList
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem(true)); // adding a spinner to the list - 0

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Wallet")); // adding a header to the list - 1
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Balance", R.drawable.ic_balance)); // - 2


        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Profile"));// adding a header to the list - 3
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Personal", R.drawable.ic_account));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Work", R.drawable.ic_work));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Address", R.drawable.ic_home));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Vehicle", R.drawable.ic_car));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Preference", R.drawable.ic_pref));


        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Other Option")); // adding a header to the list
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));

        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
                dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }






//Calendar picker
    public void selectDate(View view) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
    }
    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dobText);
        mEdit.setText(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
    }
    public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
    {


        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
        }

    }



   //Spinner

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void SelectItem(String item, int possition) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        switch(item) {
            case "Balance": fragment = new BalanceFragment(); break;
            case "Personal": fragment = new PersonalFragment(); break;
            case "Work": fragment = new WorkFragment(); break;
            case "Address": fragment = new AddressFragment(); break;
            case "Vehicle": fragment = new VehicleFragment(); break;
            case "Preference": fragment = new PreferenceFragment(); break;
            case "About": fragment = new AboutFragment(); break;
            case "Settings": fragment = new SettingsFragment(); break;
            case "Help": fragment = new HelpFragment(); break;
            default: fragment = new DefaultFragment(); break;
        }

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
        setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }




    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            if (dataList.get(position).getTitle() == null) {
                SelectItem(dataList.get(position).getItemName(), position);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: use activitys instead of fragments

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `selectItem` function.

Just replace lines `frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();`

with

`final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack("backAgain");
    transaction.commit();`

Comment: I tried not got it.. Please can you edit and send me

Comment: Not working.. throw an error in                    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);

Comment: Ok. You are very new in android. Use ' getFragmentManager()' instead of 'getSupportFragmentManager()'

Comment: Error:Wrong 2nd argument type in transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);

Comment: You have imported     import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;    try this  
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;